# C# Get MAC Address from the Access Point I am connected to

Tags: c#, .net, networking, netsh, access-point

here goes my first post in here.

I am writing a program in C# .NET Framework 4.6.1. I need to somehow get the BSSID (MAC-Address) from the Access Point a device is connected to, to put it in a string variable.

I have been searching for hours over the internet. But all I have found gives me a list of all access points.
A couple of solutions try to parse from the CMD command "netsh wlan show interfaces", but doesn´t seem to work properly. Besides I don´t like the parsing approach, it´s ugly and not performance friendly at all.

Would be golden if someone has a solution for this an could share it.

Best Regards
Enrique

Tryed the code below from another User from here, but it doesn´t seem to give anything back. The returns are empty and for example the function GetAccessPoint isn´t even triggered. (Is the only solution I found with parsing which seemed to be plausible), but as I said, I would like to stay away from parsing.

```
class AccessPoint
{
    public string SSID { get; set; }
    public string BSSID { get; set; }
    public byte Signal { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    private static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var apList = await GetSignalOfNetworks();

        foreach (var ap in apList)
        {
            WriteLine($"{ap.BSSID} - {ap.Signal} - {ap.SSID}");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static async Task<AccessPoint[]> GetSignalOfNetworks()
    {
        string result = await ExecuteProcessAsync(@"C:\Windows\System32\netsh.exe", "wlan show networks mode=bssid");

        return Regex.Split(result, @"[^B]SSID \d+").Skip(1).SelectMany(network => GetAccessPointFromNetwork(network)).ToArray();
    }

    private static AccessPoint[] GetAccessPointFromNetwork(string network)
    {
        string withoutLineBreaks = Regex.Replace(network, @"[\r\n]+", " ").Trim();
        string ssid = Regex.Replace(withoutLineBreaks, @"^:\s+(\S+).*$", "$1").Trim();

        return Regex.Split(withoutLineBreaks, @"\s{4}BSSID \d+").Skip(1).Select(ap => GetAccessPoint(ssid, ap)).ToArray();
    }

    private static AccessPoint GetAccessPoint(string ssid, string ap)
    {
        string withoutLineBreaks = Regex.Replace(ap, @"[\r\n]+", " ").Trim();
        string bssid = Regex.Replace(withoutLineBreaks, @"^:\s+([a-f0-9]{2}(:[a-f0-9]{2}){5}).*$", "$1").Trim();
        byte signal = byte.Parse(Regex.Replace(withoutLineBreaks, @"^.*(Signal|Sinal)\s+:\s+(\d+)%.*$", "$2").Trim());

        return new AccessPoint
        {
            SSID = ssid,
            BSSID = bssid,
            Signal = signal,
        };
    }

    private static async Task<string> ExecuteProcessAsync(string cmd, string args = null)
    {
        var process = new Process()
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = cmd,
                Arguments = args,
                RedirectStandardInput = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
            }
        };

        process.Start();

        string result = await process.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();

        process.WaitForExit();

        return result;
    }

    private static async Task<string> GetFakeData()
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var resourceName = "ConsoleApp2.FakeData.txt";

        using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            return await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
    }

    private static void WriteLine(string str)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: BSSID is not the same as MAC...

Comment: What does not work when you try to parse cmd ouput ?

Comment: Added information to the post. ;)

Answer (score 0):

After trial and error I found a simple solution =D

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var wlanClient = new WlanClient();
        foreach (WlanClient.WlanInterface wlanInterface in wlanClient.Interfaces)
        {
            var test = wlanInterface.CurrentConnection.wlanAssociationAttributes.Dot11Bssid;
            Console.WriteLine(test);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```